# Why bind work's when call and apply doesn't?

Tags: javascript, prototype, call, bind

I'm writing my own js library now and I am a bit have confused with this writing code:

```js
var par = document.querySelector('#par');

Element.prototype.fadeIn = function() {
  this.style.opacity = 0;
 var that = this;
  
  var last = +new Date();
  var tick = function() {
   console.log(this);
    this.style.opacity = +this.style.opacity + (new Date() - last) / 400;
    last = +new Date();

    if (+this.style.opacity < 1) {
      (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16);
    }
  };
  tick = tick.bind(that);
 tick();
};

par.fadeIn();
```

```html
<p id="par">123</p>
```

This code work's fine, but if we make tick.apply(that)instead of bind - it doesn't work! Can somebody explain me why?

Comment: Because `bind` and `apply` do totally different things!? `bind` just binds the context to a function, while `apply` ***calls*** the function immediately with a context.

Comment: I think is needed to say that apply, takes two parameters, first parameter is the scope or context and second parameter is an arry with the arguments

Comment: It also doesn't work's with call. And if we don't have an arguments - we don't need to put it on apply or call

Comment: **Clarify "doesn't work's"!** What exactly happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opacity' of undefined https://jsfiddle.net/chebotiuk/2k8jvasg/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind` and `apply` (or `call` for that matter) don't work exactly the same way.

- `apply` binds the function to the given `this` and call it right away;
- `bind` on the other hand, creates a new function bound to the given `this` but do not call it.

So those two are equivalent:

```
myFunction.call(that)

// and

myFunction.bind(that)() // <- see the extra parenthesis here
```

So in your case you can do either :

```
tick = tick.bind(that)
tick()

// OR

tick.call(that) // no need for extra assignment, the function is called right away
```

You also have another problem. In fact, when you do `tick = tick.bind(this)` you override the `tick` function defined just above ... and the `requestAnimationFrame(tick)` is able to work **because** `tick` is now bound to a `this`.

When you use call, `tick` is not modified and when the `requestAnimationFrame` fires, the `tick` function is not bound.

Here is my suggestion:

```
var tick = function () {
  //...
}.bind(that) // now tick is created and instantaneously bound to the correct `this`

tick() // first call
```

Comment: I know this rules, but in the example we call function tick() Immediately after bind, so it should be equivalent of tick.call(this);

Comment: @Pavlo Then you need to define what exactly "doesn't work" when you use `apply`/`call`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chebotiuk/2k8jvasg/

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opacity' of undefined

Comment: This is because you call `tick = tick.call(that)` and then `tick()` which is **not** a function anymore

Comment: Misspelling, sorry. I mean that tick.call(that) doesn't works. https://jsfiddle.net/chebotiuk/2k8jvasg/2/

Comment: Just edited my answer to fit your code. You should also update your question to be more specific and try to find a minimal example as @deceze suggested

Comment: Ok I know what is happening now, will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

`.bind` "binds" the context to the returned function, for later use, whereas `.apply` or `.call` invokes the function with the given context.

Comment: But we call function Immediately after bind in the same scope, not later, you see? So why we can't use call for it?